# Where is this space in my div on mobile browser coming from?

Tags: android, html, css

So I have a weird space issue in one of my divs, but only when viewing on Android webkit browser 533.1 (newest versions of webkit android browsers don't have the issue). The issue doesn't appear anywhere else, not on desktop, newer mobile devices or browsers. Etc. Only old android stock browser.

[Here is the web page](http://www.scandiafun.com/ontario). The div in question is the div with the phone number and address (toward bottom of screen, underneath facebook and twitter icons).

I figure it would be easier for you to go there and use firebug to look at the code, but if needed I can post some code here. There is just a ton of css (multiple media queries).

Here is the code for the div. The spacing occurs before the very first element in the div:

```
    <footer class="hideForDesktop" id="ont_foot">
     <div id="footer_div">
      <p id="number">909.390.3092 </p>
      <p> 1155 S. Wanamaker Ave, Ontario, CA 91761</p>


    <div id="bottom-mob-nav">
          <!-- navigation module -->
        <nav id="ontario_nav2">

    <ul>
        <li class="here"><a title="Scandia Home" href="/ontario/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a title="Scandia Rates &amp; Hours" href="/ontario/rates_hours.php">Rates &amp; Hours</a></li>
        <li><a title="Get Directions to Scandia" href="/ontario/directions.php">Directions</a></li>
        <li><a title="Rides, Games, &amp; Fun" href="/ontario/attractions.php">Attractions</a></li>
        <li><a title="Throw Your Party at Scandia!" href="/ontario/parties.php">Parties</a></li>
        <li class="show"><a title="Bring your group party to Scandia" href="/ontario/group_events.php">Group Events</a></li>
      <li><a title="Educational tours at Scandia!" href="/ontario/education.php">Education</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>   
    </div>
    <div id="end">
    <p class="boring">&copy; 2014 Scandia Family Fun Center</p>
    <p class="boring">Prices, terms and conditions subject to change without notice. Some rides may be closed during inclement weather.</p>

    <div id="otherLocs">
        <ul>
            <li class="grey"><a href="http://www.scandiafun.com/ontario">Ontario</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.scandiafun.com/sacramento">Sacramento</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.scandiafun.com/victorville">Victorville</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="other"><a href="#other">Other locations</a></div>
</div>
    </div>
            </footer>
```

I've tried setting the div#footer_div height to both auto and initial with no luck.

Screenshot:
[image: This is the space that appears on the Android browser - very awkward.]

Comment: can you give a screenshot, marking which space is that you don't want?

Comment: Screenshot posted, that space is super awkward.

Comment: The whole thing is awkward. Which part is not how you intend?

Comment: We don't need to see the php and all of that code. You should make a simple version in jsfiddle with just the important parts.

Comment: Is that magento phtml ?

Comment: @sheriffderek can you be more specific when you say "the whole thing is awkward." if you are talking about the gaping space in the screenshot (between the Facebook/twitter icons and the phone number) then yes, I agree. that is the part I'm trying to fix. but if you are giving me your opinion on my web design as a whole, I absolutely couldn't care less and such opinions are completely irrelevant to my question. but I do appreciate any help you give on this issue and don't mean to sound snotty.

Comment: I will make a jsfiddle tomorrow.

Comment: Could you just minify your html and check? Sometimes the spaces in between tags could create such issues.

Comment: Just a suggestion .hideForDesktop { display: inline-block; margin-top:0;padding-top:0; }. Its just a guess as its not happen on my android browser.

Comment: I would validate it and see what it says. (not the php) In a loaded page, view source, copy and paste that into a validator and see if something is amiss. After viewing the site, I can see what you mean now. The site looks nice. I love the home page. Very fun. You have a lot of !important declarations - I put some borders around things and tried to recreate the problem. If you have dev server or something, I would try throwing some borders on those divs (including the other footer, to see if it is involved too) and then look at it on your phone again and see if that shows you any clues.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Putting borders on the divs helped and I realized I wasn't looking at the correct div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a fix, not sure if it's the best way, but it works. I validated a bunch of problems in the HTML, but that didn't get rid of it. I put borders around all the divs and found the div that was causing the gap. I then deleted all the content from the div and found that it still had height (equal to the size of the gap. So in the CSS I set the div height to 0. This got rid of the gap, then I just had to restyle a couple of things in my CSS to make everything look the way it was and it worked.

If you look at my original post, the div that was causing the problem was `footer#ont_foot`.